# Not enough permissions to access: GET /me

Tags: permissions, linkedin-api

I'm working the **linkedin API**.

After following the documentation, I 'm getting the access Token.

Then, I'm trying to get the logged in user data, but I have this error :

> Not enough permissions to access: GET /me

I'm using this URL : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

And this as a scope : **r_basicprofile**

In my app, I have this list of permissions :

[image]

As you can see, i normally have access to **r_basicprofile**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recently LinkedIn stopped all developer access of `r_basicprofile`.

You need to authorize with `r_liteprofile` then **`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`** will return result.

Follow [Login with LinkedIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

Also Now OAuth 2.0 login is need. Process is explained in `Login with LinedIn` link ablove.

Comment: The **lite** will send less data than needed I believe. But thanks for the info. I'll ask for being certified by Linked my app, then I think I will be able to do what I need to do :)

Comment: Yes, You need to apply for LinkedIn Partner Program for r_basicprofile permission.

Comment: In this specific example shown above, the original poster shows that he/she has permission for "r_basicprofile". Linkedin's documentation says that the authorization code should be requested via "r_liteprofile". Ok. so thats fine - initially the poster sends request via "r_liteprofile". But after that, shouldn't the poster be able get information under "r_basicprofile"?  The screenshot shows the user has access to basic profile right? Also, i don't think you have to apply for "r_basicprofile". you need to apply for "r_fullprofile".

Comment: It's worth noting that LinkedIn seems to no longer support OAuth2, at least for new apps. When you make an app in the developer portal, you can only add an OpenID product which only grants the scope 'openid profile email'. Not sure of the difference between these scopes and 'r_liteprofile'. Their announcement here: https://www.linkedin.com/developers/news/featured-updates/openid-connect-authentication